# Yii - Create items list

Tags: yii

is there a simple way of creating a list with editable elements (add/remove) on a page?

Something simillar to the users managing list, where you can add and delete users.

For example, you got a table in DB with 2 columns - "Name" and "Value", and rows like 
"Onion"-"10" and "Potato"-"20". The idea is to display the table on a page and make it editable.

Sounds simple but im new in Yii, just yesterday learned about it, did first app and other stuff from guides, but there is no guide how to create things like that manually (so far i was installing widgets mostly)

Thanks

Comment: you can use CListView, it's very flexible

Comment: Is not Yii stuff, is html+css+javascript stuff. So, .. I think you need jquery for this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component you need is CGridView. Take a look to this website.
[Yii Playground](http://www.eha.ee/labs/yiiplay/index.php/en/person/admin)